# regex to change a specific string (new edit)

Tags: javascript, regex

> I'm working on a translation project, when user types i have to change some words like

**"yalama"->"yaLama",**

**"yalamak"->"yaLamak",**

**"kalamadi"->"kaLamadi",**

**"salamadi"->"saLamadi",**

My code works well for now but i have a problem: if i type only **"Lam"**, it is changing to "Lm" its okay.. But if i type **"aLamsiz"** ( i mean any **"xxxLamxxx.."** ) not working :(

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {

var text2 = $(this).val();

text2 = text2.replace(/al/g, "L");

text2 = text2.replace(/([^L]|^)am/g, '$1m');

text2 = text2.replace(/\bLam\b/g, "Lm");
 
$("#ta_1").val(text2);
  
  
});
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
  
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to the rule you're trying to enact via regular expression? Is it every lowercase L following an A? every L?

Comment: @jimmy0x52 every lowercase after L and every lowercase before L  or every lowercase after L etc etc

Comment: Do you want %ala% or %aLa% to be changed to%aLa% where % represents all characters possible ?

Comment: @D_Supreme i want %ala% to be changed to %aLa% sir